# GetModuleHandle return null

Tags: c++, mono

this artical
https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/unity/603179-hacking-mono-games.html#post3963385
that what i am trying to do, but I faced the following problem
the **GetModuleHandle** return null always and the process that have model it is runing and model loaded so what is the problem ? ?

```
HMODULE  hMono = GetModuleHandle((LPCWSTR)"mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll");
if (hMono == NULL) { printf("Error"); };
```

and i can get the hModule using **OpenProcess** Then Use **EnumProcessModulesEx**
to get the handel of the module and i get hModule but i have other question the baseModule is have to be the same of handelModule becouse when i get the handelModule of
mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll using **EnumProcessModulesEx** the handelModule of the dll was the the same of the baseModule ??!

and i try to use **GetProcAddress** and give it the handelModule and the process name it give me null too, so any help;

Comment: Get rid of the `(LPCWSTR)` cast. Its either unnecessary OR its your problem.

Comment: If you need a cast you're probably doing something wrong or at least shady. `(LPCWSTR)"mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll"` doesn't make that a wide string. Use `L"mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll"` instead or use `GetModuleHandleA` explicitly.

Comment: (Additionally whatever website or training material told you to add that cast is awful. Throw it away)

Comment: i trid GetModuleHandleA too, did not work too

Comment: at this moment i get i understant that GetModuleHandleA  get the module at current process but the model in other process so i now with **EnumProcessModulesEx **
but the GetProcAddress  give me null too

Comment: Then you have more than one problem. Perhaps the module is not actually loaded. Consider putting together a [mcve] that shows the full picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am sure that is loaded i checked it using X64dbg

Comment: that wat i am trying to to [https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/unity/603179-hacking-mono-games.html#post3963385][1]

Comment: `GetModuleHandle()` and `GetProcAddress()` only work on the calling process, you can't use them for DLLs that are loaded in a different process. What EXACTLY are you trying to accomplish? This sounds like a possible [XY Probleem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: that is what i try to do [https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/unity/603179-hacking-mono-games.html#post3963385][1]

Comment: So How Can I Dynamic load or function from the dll on other process ??

Answer (score 0):

so i was want to deals with **dll modules** in other process so i can not do that directly, i just can deals with dll modules in my current process , so you can use **pipeconnection** **with it you can create communication between two process it like server and client** but you have to handel that in you process and the other process that you want to deals with it's dll module so you will make dll moduel for server side of connection and you have two inject it in the other process and the client side of connection that will be in current process that will contact with the server and do what you want with the module in the other process then send it to the client